# A restricted product of lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

For each $p \in \mathbb{R}$, we consider $l_p (\mathbb{Z}) := \{ f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} |f(i)^p| < \infty \}$. I am trying to figure out how a certain conglomeration (a restricted product $A = \Pi'_p l_p(\mathbb{Z})$ of these spaces could work, one which features continuous linear maps $g_p : l_p(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow A$.

This could be to do with the Berkovitch completion. Potentially it could be an Ind-limit of tensor products $\otimes_{p_1, ...,p_n} l_{p_i}$, but this seems unlikely to work.

I am hoping that $A$ projects onto each $l_p(\mathbb{Z})$ as well.

Is this possible, and if not, what are some insights into how it is not possible to make a conglomeration such as this?

Comment: The spaces $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$ are growing with $p$ at least for $p>0.$ Perhaps the product of  $\ell^n(\mathbb{Z})$ suffices for your purposes.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc oh right, I intended p > 0. But given your observation about containment, isn't it the case that the largest one would simply be limsup |f(n)| < ∞?

Comment: Wait, I meant limsup Sum |f(n)| < ∞.